# java.io.IOException: Unable to open "..." as class path, filename or URL

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp

I got Java IO Exception like below:

```
Loading unnormalized dictionary from /Users/edamame/Documents/library/stanford/./data//dict/pku.non
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "/Users/edamame/Documents/library/stanford/./data//dict/pku.non" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.CorpusDictionary.readDict(CorpusDictionary.java:80)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.CorpusDictionary.<init>(CorpusDictionary.java:40)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.CorpusDictionary.<init>(CorpusDictionary.java:35)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.NonDict2.<init>(NonDict2.java:32)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.Gale2007ChineseSegmenterFeatureFactory.featuresCpC(Gale2007ChineseSegmenterFeatureFactory.java:482)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.Gale2007ChineseSegmenterFeatureFactory.getCliqueFeatures(Gale2007ChineseSegmenterFeatureFactory.java:88)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.makeDatum(CRFClassifier.java:992)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.documentToDataAndLabels(CRFClassifier.java:452)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getSequenceModel(CRFClassifier.java:1185)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.classifyMaxEnt(CRFClassifier.java:1218)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.classify(CRFClassifier.java:1128)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier$2.process(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1172)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier$2.process(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1169)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1200)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1133)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1087)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:3047)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "/Users/edamame/Documents/library/stanford/./data//dict/pku.non" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.CorpusDictionary.readDict(CorpusDictionary.java:54)
    ... 16 more
```

It seems it can not find `"/Users/edamame/Documents/library/stanford/./data//dict/pku.non"`

Here is my file locations:

```
edamame$ pwd
/Users/edamame/Documents/library/stanford/data/dict
edamame$ ls
pku    pku.gz
```

I am wondering where exactly Java is expecting my file to be? Thanks!
(PS. the original code is wrapped in python and I am on Mac)

Comment: `/./data//d ` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have double slashes `/` before `dict`:

```
 /Users/edamame/Documents/library/stanford/./data//dict/pku.non
```

Change it to:

```
/Users/edamame/Documents/library/stanford/data/dict/pku.non
```

Answer (score 0):

The `//` in your path
    /Users/edamame/Documents/library/stanford/./data//dict/pku.non

is syntactically wrong. I don‘t know how you assemble this path string but you have to fix this in order to get rid of the exception.